# Find out if sum of x numbers from a sequence of $n$ numbers is greater than a certain value

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence like so:
29, 30, 283, 12, 128, 999, ...

I wish to find out, using a single atomic computation step, if the sum of any three numbers in this sequence is greater than 1024. Is there a single formula that works over the sequence that can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: We can't for sure know the rule from the sequence.

Comment: Sort and add the largest three?

Comment: That will work, thanks!